# How to select a column that has spaces with its name?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT City, State
FROM PATIENT
WHERE [Patient Last Name] = 'Parker';
```

This is the code that I used to display city and state info for the patient whose last name is Parker. I tried [Patients Last Name], 'Patients Last Name', ['Patients Last Name'], `WHERE [Patient Last Name] IN ('Parker')` but neither of them worked. Are there any alternative ways?

Comment: Can you show your table fields exact name?

Answer (score 1):

Try `LIKE` operator with wild card-

```
SELECT City, State
   FROM PATIENT
WHERE [Patient Last Name] LIKE '*Parker';
```

> EDIT: After comment.

You table field name is `LastName`. So, try-

```
SELECT City, State FROM PATIENT WHERE [LastName] LIKE '*Parker';
```

Comment: it's not working but thanks for your help @Harun24hr

Comment: What is your column exact name for `[Patient Last Name]`?

Comment: its Patient Last Name. I copied and pasted the exact text in my Access file.

Comment: Then it must work. Can you show screenshot your your table?

Comment: I tried to upload a screenshot but StackOverflow does not allow me to upload any pics so if you're okay, can you download my screenshot or accdb file from the google drive? The name of the table is "PATIENT.": https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t_n-_d7DqOu7Xu4rfXeMvBMbiR6_qnXs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey that is `LastName`. So, try `SELECT City, State FROM PATIENT WHERE [LastName] LIKE '*Parker';`.

Comment: Actually you can use `SELECT City, State FROM PATIENT WHERE [LastName] ='Parker';` If it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it).